# React Router <Navigate> Component renders blank page until refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having a problem with the react-router v6 Navigate component. The following code doesn't work, it redirects to login?returnUrl=test but it renders a blank page, and if i refresh that same url, it renders fine.

i am using **react-router-dom ^6.14.1** package

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-haslett-w3jkqg?file=/src/App.tsx

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {

  return (
    <>

    {window.location.pathname !== '/login' ? (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigate replace to="/login?returnUrl=test" />
      </BrowserRouter>
    ) : (
      <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<h1>Login</h1>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    )}
   
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use only one `BrowserRouter` component as the top-level `Router`. And then you need to define a route for `/login` with some element to render but there is no element to render when you navigate `/login` in your code. Then you can use `Navigate` component to redirect any other path to `/login`.

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<h1>Login</h1>} />
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<Navigate replace to={`/login?returnUrl=test`} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can see the whole example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-nobel-5ntfsn?file=/src/App.js)